# mail api set from address wrongly in java

Tags: java, gmail

I am using mailapi.jar to sene mail.i am using gmail smtp details.i am setting authentication for that session.

i also setting from address in setfrom() method.
i can receive mail..but that from address was wrong .

for Example.
I am setting from address like from@gmail.com
To address like to@gmail.com

i can receive the mail in to@gmail.com id.
But the from address is my authentication id.not the from@gmail.com

Comment: `...` is the most abused punctuation on internet. Don't use it too much. Makes you look stupid.

Answer (score 0):

that may be enforced by the mail server.  decent mail servers don't generally let you impersonate anyone you like.

Comment: While I have to say, that decent email servers should at least allow you to do so and provide a configuration option for tha. Not Exchange Server 2010...